# Laurent series coefficient calculation by Cauchy’s residue theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis

For homework, I've been asked to obtain the Laurent series expansions for the following function:
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2(1-z)}$$

The question says to use Laurent's Theorem (not geometric series), which has been given as
$$\tag{1}f(z) = \sum\limits_{n= -\infty}^\infty A_nz^n $$
where
$$\tag{2}A_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint\limits_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}} dz$$

---

My initial approach to the problem was to use Cauchy’s residue theorem to evaluate the integral in $(2)$, this theorem states:
$$\oint\limits_\gamma f(z) dz = 2 \pi i \sum\limits_{a_k \in A} \mathrm{Res}_{z = a_k} f(z) $$

So in combination with $(2)$ I have,
$$A_n = \sum\limits_{a_k \in A} \mathrm{Res}_{z = a_k} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}$$
to evaluate the residue I'm using the fact that
$$\mathrm{Res}_{z = a} f(z) = \frac{1}{(m-1)!} \lim_{z \to a} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)^{m-1} ((z-a)^m f(z))$$
where $a$ is the pole and $m$ its corresponding order.

---

$f(z)$ has poles at $z = 0$ order $2$ and $z=1$ order one (simple pole),

so for the first region, $|z| < 1$, only the pole at $z = 0$ needs to be considered in the sum.

My problem is that when solving to get a function for $A_n$ without the Residual, the limit comes to $\dfrac{n+1}{0} = \infty$

Can anyone tell me if my method is wrong? or if I've failed to differentiate properly

(I apologise for how the question is formatted, I'm new to this)

---

Here is my working to get $A_n$
(INCORRECT, corrected below)

$$ A_n = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\partial}{\partial z} z^2 \frac{1}{z^{n+3}(1-z)}  $$
therefore
$$ A_n = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}(1-z)}  $$
by quotient rule
$$ A_n = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{(z^{n+1}(1-z)(0) - (1)((n+1)z^n - (n+2)z^{n+1}))}{(z^{n+1}(1-z))^2}  $$
..
$$ A_n = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z^n((n+1) - (n+2))z)}{z^{2n+2}(1-z)^2}  $$
canceling
$$ A_n = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{(n+1) - (n+2)z}{z^{n+2}(1-z)^2}  $$
applying limit
$$ A_n = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{n+1}{(0)(1)^2} = \infty  $$

---

Correct Answer
For $|z| < 1$, a = 0, m = n+3
$$ A_n = \frac{1}{((n+3) - 1)!} \lim_{z \to 0} (\frac{\partial}{\partial z})^{n+3 - 1} z^{n+3} \frac{1}{z^{n+3}(1-z)} $$
..
$$ A_n = \frac{1}{(n+2)!} \lim_{z \to 0} (\frac{\partial}{\partial z})^{n+2} \frac{1}{(1-z)} $$
..
$$ A_n = \frac{1}{(n+2)!} \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{(n+2)!}{(1-z)^{n+1}} $$
apply limit
$$ A_n = \frac{(n+2)!}{(n+2)!} = 1$$
Which is as expected due to the geometric series solution, $n \ge -2$ is a condition for the factorial function
Therefore subbing into
$$\tag{1}f(z) = \sum\limits_{n= -\infty}^\infty A_nz^n $$
gives
$$f(z) = \sum\limits_{n= -2}^\infty A_nz^n, |z| < 1 $$
THANK YOU

Comment: Your LaTeX was fine, see my edit for little ameliorations. (\operatorname{} is often used instead of \mathrm{}).

Comment: You should be differentiating $\frac{1}{1-z} = z^{n+2} \cdot \frac{f(z)}{z^n}$ and you shouldn't get $\infty$, but $1$ each time.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that although $f$ has a double pole at $z=0$, $f(z)/z^{n+1}$ has a pole or order $n+3$, and it's the residue of this that is relevant, not the residue of $f$ itself.

Comment: Thank you, I'll correct it and see what happens